# What is the difference between the given code below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the difference between the given code below.

```
df.ix['2008']
```

and

```
df.ix[2008]
```

I just wanna know what 'ix' is doing here and

the difference between both line of code.

Comment: One is a string, and one is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas.DataFrame.ix[ ] is both Label and Integer based slicing technique.

Below line of code will check if '2008' is a column and share all the rows of it. If it isn't a column, it will throw a KeyError.

```
df.ix[:,'2008']
```

whereas second line you have mentioned checks for 2008 as a index and returns a series.